# Regarding attributes of an instance

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

```py
class Empl():
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.f = first
        self.l = last
        # Just checking something
        self.full = self.f + ' ' + self.l

first = Empl('Mickey', 'Mouse')

first.f = "Ricky"

print(first.full)  # It prints Mickey Mouse
```

Why is that change in `first.f` is not reflected at `first.full`?

Comment: Because you've constructed a new string, not an uncompiled structure of strings

Comment: If you want it to be dynamically calculated from the *current* values of those attributes, use `@property`.

Comment: wdym by that , i am new to OOP so i dont quite get ya . mind elaborating on that ?

Answer (score 0):

Because `self.full`is only set once, when the object is made. It is not updated if you change `self.f`.

You need a method that updates the value of full when ever something is changed:

```
class empl():
    def __init__(self,fist,last):
        self.f=fist
        self.l=last
        #Just checking something
        self.full=self.f + ' ' + self.l

    def change_f(self, new_val):
        self.f = new_val
        # Make sure to update
        self.full=self.f + ' ' + self.l

first=empl('Micki','Mouse')

first.change_f("Ricky")

print(first.full) # Will now print Ricky Mouse
```

Comment: Just because its not something abstract "pythonic" way, doesn't mean it's incorrect. I will however edit to reflect that whats important here is not the "setter" function, but the fact that `full` needs to be updated

Comment: @Artog thanks for replying and can I reconfirm that when i reassign my empl first name like first.f='Ricky' does it updates my original value or does it creates a new one ?

Comment: @no_mad strings are immutable, you *can't* update the original value.

Comment: The problem with a setter-type method is not just abstract: you can still directly set `self.f`, (or `l`, or even `full`) which is a bit of a "foot gun". If `full` is a read-only property *based on* `f` and `l`, it's harder to accidentally do the wrong thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes you are right . so when i do that it basically creates a new attribute and next time when i call that attribute it will give me the newer one ? am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

To make `self.fullname` depend on `self.f` and `self.l`, make it a *property*:

```
class Empl():
    def __init__(self, first, last):
        self.f = first
        self.l = last

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return self.f + " " + self.l
```

Now the value of `self.fullname` will be computed on-the-fly using the
current values of `self.f` and `self.l`, rather than storing a string
created from (possibly out-of-date) first and last names.

Note that as-is, you cannot change the `fullname` directly, only the first and last names individually. That's a feature. (How to make `fullname` assignable is beyond the scope of this answer.)

---

The expression `self.f + ' ' + self.l` is not linked to the objects referenced by `self.f` or `self.l`; graphically, you start with

```
(1)
self.f ------>  "foo"
self.l ------>  "bar"
```

and end with

```
(2)
self.f ------>  "foo"
self.l ------>  "bar"
self.full --->  "foo bar"
```

not something like

```
(3)
self.f ------>  "foo"  <----\
                  " "  <----+---self.full
self.l ------>  "bar"  <----/
```

`self.full` is an independent object, unaffected by changes to either `self.f` or `self.l`.

---

Even the above is a *slight* lie. Any particular Python implementation *might* share memory between the three string objects, because `str` objects are *immutable*. You can't change the actual `str` that `self.f` references to get something like

```
(4)
self.f ------>  "fpo"  <----\
                  " "  <----+---self.full
self.l ------>  "bar"  <----/
```

with the change of `foo` to `foo` affecting both `self.f` and `self.full`. You can only change what `self.f` refers to, like

```
(5)
          +--> "fpo"
          |
self.f ---+     "foo"  <----\
                  " "  <----+---self.full
self.l ------>  "bar"  <----/
```

However, any such memory-sharing is *only* an implentation detail, and not something visible from Python itself. Effectively, you can only "see" (2), whether the strings `"foo"` and `"bar"` are represented once or twice in memory.